# How to use sweetalert2 to Restart (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, restart, sweetalert2

Old code:
`restart(" Game Over. Try again!");`

```
    playerLives = 10;
    playerLivesCount.textContent = playerLives;
    setTimeout(() => window.alert(text), 100);
};
```

This works great in a popup window.
I need a pretty popup so i decided to use sweetalert2.

New code:
`Swal.fire(" Game Over. Try again!");`

But now "OK" button does not run the function Restart.

How to use restart with Swal.fire ?
[image]

Comment: There's not enough context here.  What is the restart function, and where does it come from?  What was the original functionality?

Comment: @micahlt I add more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `restart` is a function that restarts the game, you could write the alert as follows:

```
Swal.fire(" Game Over. Try again!").then(() => {
  restart();
});
```

You would also want to remove the logic from the `restart` function that previously fired an alert.

Comment: it works. but there is still a popup with message "undefined". is it possible to get rid of it?

Comment: Where is the `restart` function defined?  What does it do?

Comment: I updated the question - added information about the function restart

Comment: So just remove the second to last line that says `setTimeout(() => window.alert(text), 100);`.